# DataTemplate's TextBlock's KeyDown handler is not called

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, textblock, keydown

I have following data template defined:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="hierarchicalTreeNodeTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                       MouseLeftButtonDown="treeViewTextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                       KeyDown="treeViewTextBlock_KeyDown"
                       />
        </DataTemplate>
```

This data template is used to render some of WPF TreeViewItems.
For some reason, the MouseLeftButtonDown handler is called as expected when user clicks on a tree item that happened to be a TextBlock, but the KeyDown handler is not called when the same item is selected and any keyboard key is pressed.
Any ideas what could be wrong here?
Thanks.